# WooCommerce: Custom loop for best selling products of the last 30 days

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show the best selling products of the last 30 days.
I already have a code for showing bestseller products. But these are the total sales of the shop.
Is there any option to limit the product sales to 30 days?

I guess the meta key `total_sales` isn't the correct way to do this, right?

Here's my current loop:

```
$args_basic = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'meta_key'          => 'total_sales',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
);
```

Comment: Words to the wise, don't delete fresh new questions. I was redacting an answer to your merge query question and wasted 15 minutes.

Comment: @amarinediary I'm so sorry! There were several close requests for that question :-( Should I open it again? But I think it get closed in a few minutes after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no way to test the following but at first glance it should be working from the gecko.

- We query last month orders via [`wc_get_orders`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-functions.html#function_wc_get_orders) and the `date_after` argument.
- We then retrieve each order items IDs and push them to a new `Array`.
- Fianlly we can use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to count the number of time each IDs shows up.

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'wpso_67421248' );
  
function wpso_67421248() {

   $orders = wc_get_orders(
        array(
            'limit' => -1,
            'status' => array_map( 'wc_get_order_status_name', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
            'date_after' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-1 month' ) ),
            'return' => 'ids',
        )
   );

   $identifiers = array();

   foreach ( $orders as $order ) {

        $items = wc_get_order( $order )->get_items();

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            array_push( $identifiers, $item->get_product_id() );

        };

    };

    var_dump( rsort( array_count_values( $identifiers ) ) );

};
```

Comment: Updated, added `rsort()` (sort arrays in descending order.) to the result dump.